# Automation of PowerShell from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, powershell, delphi-xe8

Can PowerShell be automated?  I.e. is there a COM interface to PowerShell that can be imported into Delphi as a type-library interface to automate it, and if so, what is the relevant file name(s)?

Googling, etc, I've found numerous references to automating things from *within* a PowerShell script, but I haven't been able to find anything to say whether or not I could control PowerShell itself via COM as I could it it were MS Word or whatever, and maybe receive events from it.  What I'm wanting to do is to hand it a command from within a Delphi app to execute some arbitrary CmdLet and get status information back from it while it's executing the script (otherwise I'd make do with doing a ShellExecute on it).

I'm not sure whether the fact that I have been able to find anything is because PowerShell is by design not automatable or because I haven't managed to frame an effective query that filters out all the automation that can be done using PowerShell as a script host.

This is using XE8 on Win7 64-bit or its Win10 upgrade, btw.

Comment: Thanks, @Craig.  I will have a look in the morning when I'm feeling a bit fresher.  Too much excitement pondering ways to split up a memo today ;=).

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment, the link was http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72616/ looking at it now it may be no good for you I don't know, it says `Running PowerShell Scripts From TestComplete`

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://delphidabbler.com/software/consoleapp .It is a class to interact with a console window

Comment: Some questions: (1) When you say you want to run some "arbitrary CmdLet", do you mean you  want to run a .ps1 script, or do you mean really want to run an arbitrary cmdlet such as Get-ChildItem? (2) What sort of information do you want to send from PowerShell to Delphi? (3) Is your Delphi app a VCL forms app (as opposed to a console app)? (4) Is the PowerShell script a long-running thing, or is it something where it would be okay to launch it and wait for it to finish?

Comment: Have you seen this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2008/07/26/calling-a-powershell-script-from-your-net-code.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on RaelB's suggestion of http://delphidabbler.com/software/consoleapp:

This worked for me since Powershell itself can be run as a console app. If you wanted to run CmdLet "abc -param", then you would call the Execute method of a TPJConsoleApp instance:

> app.Execute ('powershell -command abc -param')

Peter Johnson (delphiDabbler) provides several examples for interacting with the console app via pipes, files, etc. to get your status information back from the Cmdlet's stdOut (stdIn and stdErr are also available).  Working code can be quickly derived from the most appropriate example.

Optionally you may want to provide additional parameters for powershell:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help

Comment: Thanks for this.  The project I had in mind never quite got off the ground, but I'll look into it again when I catch up on some other stuff.  meanwhile +1 for the heads-up.